# How to write a method like string.Format with intellisense support

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, intellisense

Consider a method to write with a `format` parameter like `string.Format`'s frist parameter. As you know the Intellisense is aware of first parameter's constraints and checks for its consistency with parameters. How can I write such method.

As a simple example, consider a wrap of `string.Format` like:

```
public string MyStringFomratter(string formatStr, params object[] arguments)
{
    // Do some checking and apply some logic
    return string.Format(formatStr, arguments);
}
```

How can I say to the compiler or IDE that `formatStr` is something like `string.Format`'s first parameter?

So if I have some code like this:

```
var x = MyStringFormatter("FristName: {0}, LastName: {1}", firstName);
// This code should generate a warning in the IDE
```

Comment: You cannot make Visual Studio analyze parameter content for you. But you can use Visual Studio add-in (e.g. ReSharper) which verifies parameters count for String.Format

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy ye Resharper checks that just for String.Format, but what about my own methods? Is there a way?

Comment: Resharper checks that for EVERY method, you don't think the makers of Reshaper hardcoded checks against one method name or another

Comment: @MikeSW actually I do think that method name is hardcoded - how ReSharper will understand my intent? Whether I'm passing format string with parameters I'm going to use, or it just string which I'm going e.g. save to database, and parameters not related to that string

Comment: @mehrandvd Visual Studio will not do that for you, because there is no such functionality by default - it should be some add-in.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I wish there was an attribute to put on the parameters and tell intellisense that it's a string format.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Thanks, in the future, I hope Roslyn helps in such situations.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You might be right, it seems it doesn't trigger on my own ToFormat() method

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy would you post your comments as answer!?

Comment: @mehrandvd sure, done :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot make Visual Studio analyze parameter content for you - it simply verifies that code is compilable, and `String.Format` is compilable even if you haven't specified parameters for all placeholders. But you can use Visual Studio add-in (e.g. [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) or [CodeRush](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b14bb191-2d39-4e82-8bd2-826bf79237a0)) which analyzes placeholders count for `String.Format` formatting string and verifies parameters count passed to this method.

BTW I'm not using ReSharper but looks like it has support for marking any method as string formatting method - [Defining Custom String Formatting Methods](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__String_Formatting_Methods.html). You just should annotate your method with `StringFormatMethodAttribute` attribute:

```
[StringFormatMethod("formatStr")]
public string MyStringFomratter(string formatStr, params object[] arguments)
{
    // Do some checking and apply some logic
    return string.Format(formatStr, arguments);
}
```

Comment: It's the exact answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: What is going to happen when you no longer use resharper?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't issue a warning for `String.Format` with wrong number of parameters.
However, if you want intellisense support, precede your method with `///` and it will create a template for documenting the method. Fill in the documentation and it will appear in the intellisense when you use the method.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm looking for a way to tell Resharper about the behavior of my method parameters.

Comment: I think the methods like String.Format are hard coded in Resharper. Sorry.